# How to check if an integer value is in a given array of ranges and which array element

Tags: java, arrays, json-deserialization

Got a json file which loads some configurations array as below :

configs.json

```
[
  {
    "category":"A",
    "scoreMargins" : [[12], [9,11], [7,9], [5,6], [3,4]]
  },
  {
    "category":"B",
    "scoreMargins" : [[3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10], [11, 12]]
  }
]
```

The `scoreMargins` are not in one exact format, so its de-serialized as an object at the moment. But number of ranges(or single value) are always 5.

CalculationValues.java

```
 public class StressTestCategoryCalculationValues {
   private String category;
   private Object scoreMargins;
 }
```

service :

```
List<CalculationValues> values = mapper.readValue(CalculationValues.class.getResourceAsStream('configs.json'),
            mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, CalculationValues.class));

Optional<CalculationValues> configA = values.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getCategory().equals("A"))
            .findFirst();

int sumA = xx;
if (configA.isPresent()) {
    // logic
}
```

I want to get which `scoreMargins` array element holds the range that `sumA` falls into..

Ex :

```
"scoreMargins" : [[3,4], [5,8], [8,11], [11,12], [12, 13]], 

 sumA = 7, result ??

 Desired result =  2 (3rd element)
```

What would be the easiest approach to do this?

Comment: Is `configs.json` intentionally `"scoreMargins" : [12, [10,11], [7,9], [5,6], [3,4]]` or should that have been `"scoreMargins" : [[12], [10,11], [7,9], [5,6], [3,4]]`, if you make it consistently an array of arrays it'll be easier to deserialize.

Comment: Seems like `scoreMargins` should be type `int[][]` (instead of Object).  Then loop over `scoreMargins` to find where `sumaA` fits.

Comment: Also I am not sure what your result should be? Do you want to return the array, the digit, the whole CalculationValues object?

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz just the array index of the particular element would be enough

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but when using json, it does not guarantee to retain array order when being passed around between apis, therefore there is no guarantee your index is in any way accurate without returning the exact input json as a string with your index...

Therefore this is more of an example of deserializing 2d arrays in json.

```java
int getIndex(CalcValues cv, int sumA) {

    for (List<Integer> sm : cv.getScoreMargins()) {
        sm = sm.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (sm.get(0) == sumA) {
            return cv.getScoreMargins().indexOf(sm);
        }

        if (sm.size() > 1 && sm.get(0) <= sumA && sm.get(1) >= sumA) {
            return cv.getScoreMargins().indexOf(sm);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

class CalcValues {

    private String category;
    private List<List<Integer>> scoreMargins;

    // getter and setter

}
```